# iframe url is opening in current window instead of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an advertiser website which I am trying to open inside an iframe. (unfortunately i cant provide you with the url) but instead of opening inside an iframe it loads up the url in the same tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('public/scripts/core/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url("public/scripts/core/core.js");?>"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="iframe_form" method="POST" action="">
    <?php echo $user_id." ".$offer_id;?>




</form>
<iframe src='{{URL}}' id="qual" name="qual"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var url = "<?php echo site_url('api/check_pixel');?>";
        var offer_id = "<?php echo $offer_id;?>";
        var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id;?>";
        var intId = setInterval(
            function(){check_pixel(url,offer_id,user_id);},1000
        )
        ;

    });

</script>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would have to know the contents of the iframe.  My guess would be the link you are clicking inside the iframe has target="_new" or _blank or _parent when it would need to have target="_self".

Comment: The advertiser might also be using anti-iframe code making it so you cannot put their pages inside an iframe

Comment: I tried it in here http://jsfiddle.net/HnXFj/45/ with their link and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the iframe src to **echo site_url;** inside of aPHP tag. I would heva just showed the code.

Comment: my first attempt was echo url, and then i tried javascript to populate src on click but none of them worked

Comment: I use this all the time in my php pages.  you should be able to edit this and make it work.  This is my working code

    <iframe name="name" id="id" width="1200" height="500" src='<?php echo $row_Recordset1['url']; ?>'></iframe>

Comment: Issue was that the advertiser was using anti iframe code. Adding sandbox to iframe fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like this?

```
<iframe src='<?php echo $**SITEURLVARIABLE** ?>' id="qual" name="qual"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var url = "**SITEURLHERE**";
        var offer_id = "<?php echo $offer_id;?>";
        var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id;?>";
        var intId = setInterval(
            function(){check_pixel(url,offer_id,user_id);},1000
        )
        ;

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src='{{URL}}' id="qual" name="qual" id="myframe" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Adding sandbox (html5 feature) worked for me. I have also added

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

just in case it does to try to load the page outside iframe.